# Differentiate a function and identify the region on which the function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am given $f(z) = \sqrt{e^z + 1}$

I have found $f'(z) = \frac{e^z}{2\sqrt{e^z +1}} $

Is this function analytic everywhere because $ e^z $is analytic everywhere?

Comment: $z$ is analytic everywhere, but $\sqrt z$ is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square root function is not analytic along a fixed choice of branch cut, usually the negative real axis. So the composition will be analytic except at those points for which $e^z + 1$ is a negative real number.

Also, you will run into problems at places where the derivative fails to exist. This will happen when $e^z + 1 = 0$, because the denominator will be undefined. $e^z = -1$ precisely when $z = (2n+1)\pi i$, for integer $n$.

Answer (score 0):

A general comment about somethingh that simplified my life: as @zhw points out, a composition $f\circ g$ is analytic whenever the image $\{g(z)\: z \in \mathbb C \}$ falls into the subset of $\mathbb C $ where $f$ is analytic. Not too deep of a comment, but has been often useful for me. Hope I am not out of line for posting something like this.